# Adding an attribute to a Relationship

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to load a CSV file using `LOAD FROM CSV` and build a relationship. I have a crossover table that I am using to support a many to many relationship. For my example I will use two (2) primary nodes, Car and Driver.

A Car can be driven by one or more Drivers and a Driver can drive one or more Cars.

My cross over table looks like this

```
CarID (int)
DriverID (int)
```

Here is my code to successfully load it into Neo4j

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'FILE:///CarToDriverXFER.csv' AS row FIELDTERMINATOR ','

MATCH (c:Cars {carID:row.carID})

MATCH (d:Drivers {driverID:row.driverID})

MERGE (c)-[:DRIVES]->(d)
```

I want to add an attribute into this relationship. Now the table looks like this:

```
CarID (int)

DriverID (int)

Rating (int)
```

I am not sure how to do this. I know how to do this if the object is a node but I am not getting the syntax correct with regards to build a relationship. Here is my attempt at a solution but I am getting an error.

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'FILE:///CarToDriverXFER.csv' AS row FIELDTERMINATOR ','

MATCH (c:Cars {carID:row.carID})

MATCH (d:Drivers {driverID:row.driverID})

CREATE ({Rating:row.Rating})

MERGE (c)-[:DRIVES]->(d)
```

The above script loaded the relationships but the attribute "Rating" is not listed on the attribute.

Can anyone offer help?

Answer (score 6):

You can add the attribute to the relationship the same way you add attributes to nodes, that is:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'FILE:///CarToDriverXFER.csv' AS row FIELDTERMINATOR ','
MATCH (c:Cars {carID:row.carID})
MATCH (d:Drivers {driverID:row.driverID})
// adding 'Rating' attribute to ':Drives' relationship between 'c' and 'd'
MERGE (c)-[:DRIVES {Rating:row.Rating}]->(d)
```